# jquery div tag not closing after post request and alert not working in chrome browser

Tags: php, jquery

I have a few question about jquery
here is my code

```
    <?php $date=$_POST["user"];  require_once("test1.php"); 
    function createReportTable($result, $title){ }?>
        <html>
            <head>
               <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("hi");
       $('.show_hide').hide();
                 $('.addperm').submit(function(){
                      var query = $('#user').val(); 
                      $.post("test.php", query, function(response){
                        alert(response);
                      }); }); $('.show_hide').show();  });
        </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form action= 'test.php' class = 'addperm' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='user' id='user' /><br />
        <input type='submit' value='Add' id="add">
        </form>
                <div id="wrapper" class="show_hide">
                    <div id="center">
                        <div>
                            <?php createReportTable(getReport($date), "xyz"); ?>
                        </div>
                        </div> </div>
```

So here are my questions
1) I tried to use alert function and it is not working in chrome. firefox it works fine. Why is that so?
2) I am trying to hide and unhide the div tag but it does not seem to work at all in chrome but in firefox it is hiding the dive div tag but not showing it again.

I think the reason for the div tag not showing again is after the $post the page is refreshed and hence it is not working. If this is the problem how do I solve it? if this is not the issue then what might be the issue. and why is the chrome browser not working.

If I am not concerned with the div tags the code is working perfectly and giving the output as required in all the browsers.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Copied this code directly and tested it out in Chrome. Seemed to work just fine (alert box came up).

Comment: I am using linux mint is that an issue? @AlexMorrise

Comment: Well, whatever is in "test1.php" might be an issue.

Comment: In the test1.php there is the function getReport() which is getting data from the database.I am using PDO to get the data from the database. there is nothing else there @AlexMorrise